# Xcode: None of the input catalogs contained a matching app icon / launch image set

Tags: ios, xcode, build, xcode8, asset-catalog

My Xcode started behaving weirdly, when trying to Archive an iOS project.

- All files are in their original places
- I tried to return to a previous commit
- Tried restarting Xcode
- I tried as well clean build and manually deleting entire build folder
- Changing these in project settings `Asset Catalog App Icon Set Name` and `Asset Catalog Launch Image Set Name`
- Rebuilding Images.xcassets

None of those helped and I am still seeing the same error.

The error always occurs in the last phase of the build process (`Compile asset catalogs`),.

Xcode console:

```
CompileAssetCatalog build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/reactproject/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/reactproject.app build/Build/Intermediates/reactproject/Images.xcassets
    cd /Users/user/Developer/reactproject/ios
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool --output-format human-readable-text --notices --warnings --export-dependency-info /Users/user/Developer/reactproject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/reactproject/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/reactproject.build/Release-iphoneos/reactproject.build/assetcatalog_dependencies --output-partial-info-plist /Users/user/Developer/reactproject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/reactproject/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/reactproject.build/Release-iphoneos/reactproject.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist --app-icon AppIcon --launch-image LaunchImage --compress-pngs --enable-on-demand-resources YES --sticker-pack-identifier-prefix com.example.reactproject.sticker-pack. --target-device iphone --target-device ipad --minimum-deployment-target 8.0 --platform iphoneos --product-type com.apple.product-type.application --compile /Users/user/Developer/reactproject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/reactproject/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/reactproject.app /Users/user/Developer/reactproject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/reactproject/Images.xcassets

/* com.apple.actool.errors */
/Users/user/Developer/reactproject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/reactproject/Images.xcassets: error: None of the input catalogs contained a matching app icon set named  "AppIcon".
/Users/user/Developer/reactproject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/reactproject/Images.xcassets: error: None of the input catalogs contained a matching launch image set named  "LaunchImage".
/* com.apple.actool.notices */
/Users/user/Developer/reactproject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/reactproject/Images.xcassets: warning: Failed to read file attributes for "/Users/user/Developer/reactproject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/reactproject/Images.xcassets"
    Failure Reason: No such file or directory
/* com.apple.actool.compilation-results */
/Users/user/Developer/reactproject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/reactproject/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/reactproject.build/Release-iphoneos/reactproject.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a build setting called Asset Catalog Launch Image Set Name (`ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_LAUNCHIMAGE_NAME`) that you need to clear out from the target in Xcode's build settings (you can also delete the corresponding line from your `.pbxproj` file in your favorite text editor).

Background: A few years ago, with the profusion of different device sizes, Apple switched to using a canned UI file (`.xib`) for the launch screen in place of a series of static images. This used to be exposed in the General tab of the target UI but it's now been long enough since it was used that the removed it, so you have to go spelunking in the Build Settings tab.

Answer (score 0):

The file Images.xcassets was re-generated by Asset Catalog Creator tool, removing it and adding it back to the project solved the problem. When adding the file into Xcode project, the referencing needs to be set correctly.